# How to suppress sound when opening a dialogform in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, audio, showdialog

I have a form with a textbox, when pressing enter another form2 is opened.
How can I suppress sound when form2 is opened?

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.Handled = True
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        My.Forms.Form2.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Sound happens when, you press a key or when the form is opened?

Comment: Override ProcessCmdKey instead, and handle the Enter key press there. I think that will work. You really shouldn't be doing this. Enter in a TextBox either creates a new line or is invalid. It shouldn't magically open a new form.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by changing the code slightly and moving it into the KeyPress event instead of KeyDown

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyKeyPress
     If e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
        e.Handled = True
        My.Forms.Form2.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: And how is this any different than OP code? The only difference is you left out `SuppressKeyPress` and different handler, can you replicate the OP issue and also verify your proposed solution works?

Comment: @Zaggler. Actually it is different. It's in the Keypress event which for whatever reason does not cause the ding sound. The OP's code was in the KeyDown event and causes it to ding when the showdialog is executed. It also solves the OP's question based off his code.

Comment: I just confirmed that this answer works like a charm!